# Strange result searching with to_tsquery under Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, postgresql-9.2, tsvector

I got a strange result searching for an expression like `pro-physik.de` with tsquery.

If I ask for `pro-physik:*` by tsquery I want to get all entries starting with `pro-physik`. Unfortunately those entries with `pro-physik.de` are missing.

Here are 2 examples to demonstrate the problem:

Query 1:

```
select 
    to_tsvector('simple', 'pro-physik.de') @@ 
    to_tsquery('simple', 'pro-physik:*') = true
```

Result 1: `false` (should be `true`)

Query 2:

```
select 
    to_tsvector('simple', 'pro-physik.de') @@
    to_tsquery('simple', 'pro-p:*') = true
```

Result 2: `true`

Has anybody an idea how I could solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

The core of the problem is that the parser will parse `pro-physik.de` as a hostname:

```
SELECT alias, token FROM ts_debug('simple', 'pro-physik.de');

 alias |     token
-------+---------------
 host  | pro-physik.de
(1 row)
```

Compare this:

```
SELECT alias, token FROM ts_debug('simple', 'pro-physik-de');
      alias      |     token
-----------------+---------------
 asciihword      | pro-physik-de
 hword_asciipart | pro
 blank           | -
 hword_asciipart | physik
 blank           | -
 hword_asciipart | de
(6 rows)
```

Now `pro-physik` and `pro-p` are *not* hostnames, so you get

```
SELECT to_tsquery('simple', 'pro-physik:*');
              to_tsquery
---------------------------------------
 'pro-physik':* & 'pro':* & 'physik':*
(1 row)

SELECT to_tsquery('simple', 'pro-p:*');
         to_tsquery
-----------------------------
 'pro-p':* & 'pro':* & 'p':*
(1 row)
```

The first `tsquery` will not match because `physik` is not a prefix of `pro-physik.de`, and the second will match because `pro-p`, `pre` and `p` all three are prefixes.

As a workaround, use full text search like this:

```
select 
   to_tsvector('simple', replace('pro-physik.de', '.', ' ')) @@ 
   to_tsquery('simple', replace('pro-physik:*', '.', ' '))
```

Comment: The main problem seems to be not the dot but rather the behavior of the ts-parser to avoid splitting hostnames. The same thing is with e-mail-addresses:

Comment: Do you or anyone else have any idea how to configure the fulltext search ignoring hostnames, e-mail-addresses e.g.?

Comment: You cannot do that unless you want to write a new parser (in C). I told you the workaround: replace the dot with a space, then the parser will find no hostnames. Just apply `replace(<string>, '.', ' ')` to the strings before you use them in full text search.